# Reading in multiple hdf5 files and appending them to a new dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, hdf5, h5py

I have a list of `hdf5` files which I would like to open and read in the appropriate values into a new dictionary and eventually write to a text file. I don't necessarily know the values, so the user defines them in an array as an input into the code. The number of files needed is defined by the number of days worth of data the user wants to look at.

```
new_data_dic = {}

for j in range(len(values)):
    new_data_dic[values[j]] = rbsp_ephm[values[j]]
for i in (np.arange(len(filenames_a)-1)+1):
        rbsp_ephm = h5py.File(filenames_a[i])
        for j in range(len(values)):
            new_data_dic[values[j]].append(rbsp_ephm[values[j]])
```

This works fine if I only have one file, but if I have two or more it seems to close the key? I'm not sure if this is exactly what is happening, but when I ask what `new_data_dic` is, for values it gives `{'Bfs_geo_a': <Closed HDF5 dataset>,...` which will not write to a text file. I've tried closing the hdf5 file before opening the next (`rbsp_ephm.close()`) but I get the same error.

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your problem... you are trying to create a list of hdf5 dataset? 
Or did you just forget the `[()]` to acces the values in the dataset itself?

Here is a simple standalone example that works just fine :

```
import h5py

# File creation 
filenames_a = []
values = ['values/toto', 'values/tata', 'values/tutu']

nb_file = 5
tmp = 0
for i in range(nb_file):
    fname = 'file%s.h5' % i
    filenames_a.append(fname)
    file = h5py.File(fname, 'w')
    grp = file.create_group('values')
    for value in values:
        file[value] = tmp
        tmp += 1
    file.close()

# the thing you want
new_data_dict = {value: [] for value in values}

for fname in filenames_a:
    rbsp_ephm = h5py.File(fname, 'r')
    for value in values:
        new_data_dict[value].append(rbsp_ephm[value][()])

print new_data_dict
```

It returns :

```
{'values/tutu': [2, 5, 8, 11, 14], 'values/toto': [0, 3, 6, 9, 12], 'values/tata': [1, 4, 7, 10, 13]}
```

Does it answer your question?

Comment: I was trying to take the data from a hdf5 file and put it into a dictionary open a new file and take that data, and append it to the data already in the dictionary. What seemed to be happening is that it works fine if you have one file, but the minute you open the second file, the first gets closed and forgotten.

Comment: No if think that it is just when you do `rbsp_ephm[values[j]]`, it is not the actual data that you handle (it's the `HDF5 dataset` object), you have to do `rbsp_ephm[values[j]][()]` instead. Try to print both to be sure...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not directly the good solution, but you could try to extract data as numpy arrays which are a more flexible format rather than the h5py dataset one. See below how to do it:

```
>>> print type(file['Average/u'])
<class 'h5py.highlevel.Dataset'>
>>> print type(file['Average/u'][:])
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

And just in case, you should try to use a more "pythonic" way for your loop, that is:

```
for j in values:
    new_data_dic[j] = rbsp_ephm[j]
```

instead of:

```
for j in range(len(values)):
    new_data_dic[values[j]] = rbsp_ephm[values[j]]
```